# Does the deletion of Chromosome 20 cause immunity against prion disease?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

I was reading recently about prion disease and it caught my attention that a normal prion protein is coded n chromosome 20, therefore, in order for an infectious prion protein to attack, there must be already normal unsedimented prion proteins, does that mean the deletion of chromosome 20 in meiosis lead to immunity against prion disease, since the protein is not coded, that is if the human survives without chromosome 20

Comment: "That is if the human survives without chromosome 20". I suggest you consider the likelihood of that being true or do some investigation to discover how many other genes are encoded on chromosome 20. You may then wish to delete your question.

Comment: I read an article that says chromosome 20 deletion occurs so I am quite unsure, I mean why would I ask in the first place

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that a person can survice without chromosome 20. Please cite the article that leads you to think it possible.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology phenolicdeath. Including a link to the article will help other users to answer your question. It sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I see one report of a viable autosomal monosomy,

(https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM196710122771502)

but in general, they are not survivable.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/4086989
https://www.biology.iupui.edu/biocourses/N100/2k2humancsomaldisorders.html
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29164644

A better question would be if person with a deletion or natural knockout of that gene are susceptible to that prion disease.  Those subjects likely exist in larger numbers, though it's likely that few have been exposed to any particular prion disease.